# AngularJS - ng-bind-html not working with

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I am getting HTML data from the database and the data is like --

```
"<span class=\"ui-like \" data-tipcontent=\"initialmessage\" data-contentid=\"4f3f9827-364a-41b8-adf4-a5c4ada64b8d\" data-contenttypeid=\"f7d226ab-d59f-475c-9d22-4a79e3f0ec07\" data-initialcount=\"5\" data-initialstate=\"true\" data-readonly=\"false\" data-initialmessage=\"You and <span class="who-likes">4 others</span> like this\" data-format=\"{message}\" data-configuration=\"Format=%7Bmessage%7D\"></span>
```

I am using `<div ng-bind-html="connection.LikeCountMessage"></div>` to render this html, but it is not rendering the entire HTML. It is just rendering

```
<div ng-bind-html="connection.LikeCountMessage" class="ng-binding">
<span class="ui-like "></span>
</div>
```

I am expecting something like

```
<div ng-bind-html="connection.LikeCountMessage" class="ng-binding">
<span class="ui-like ">You and 4 other like this</span>
</div>
```

How do i fix this? what am I missing?

Comment: The string you posted is not a valid string. The HTML it contains has a span inside an attribute of another span. Not sure why you expect what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-bind-html-unsafe instead of ng-bind-html